# Dojo load failes with error 'Uncaught string.substitute could not find key "!actionBarTemplate" in template' after recent dojo update

Tags: dojo

I have updated dojo for one of my project which uses the framework. After the recent update I noticed a weird error 'Uncaught string.substitute could not find key "!actionBarTemplate" in template' and dojo load fails. I tried to research online about the error and track from the source files but could not figure out the cause of it. If any of you have an idea of why this might happen or has encountered a similar situation, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the template which is causing the issue?

Comment: I get these errors trying to run 1.12.0-rc1 on an app that is currently using 1.11.2.  IMO, this is a regression bug in Dojo since I should not get any errors changing Dojo when I have made no changes to the app's code.  I also get errors: `dojo/parser::parse() error string.substitute could not find key "!nameAttrSetting" in template`

Comment: **Update**: 1.12.0-rc2 does not give me the errors noted in previous comment.  Have not done a complete evaluation, but now our app load correctly.  With rc1, it did not load due to errors.

Comment: @ewh Yeah even I noticed the same thing. Everything looks fine after the update.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown if the `dijit/_TemplatedMixin` couldn't find a key that is present in the template but not in the widget, exactly in the `_stringRepl` function that is called in the `buildRendering` of a widget.

Here is what returns this function:

```
return string.substitute(tmpl, this, function(value, key){
    if(key.charAt(0) == '!'){ value = lang.getObject(key.substr(1), false, _this); }
    if(typeof value == "undefined"){ throw new Error(className+" template:"+key); }
    if(value == null){ return ""; }
```

Note the `throw new Error` part?

Now, the only templates containing a key `!actionBarTemplate` are
  - dijit\templates\TooltipDialog.html
  - dijit\templates\Dialog.html

So, do you have a widget that use this templates and does not have property `actionBarTemplate`? Probably adding the property `actionBarTemplate: ""` to does widgets fix your issue.

Have in mind that if you have in your templates, for example `${title}`, this will end up asking if `this.title` exist, so, make sure that at least you have `title: null`

Hope it helps